# python(numpy) -- create array and how to implement an expression

Tags: python, numpy

i have this :

```
npoints=10

vectorpoint=random.uniform(-1,1,[1,2])
experiment=random.uniform(-1,1,[npoints,2])
```

and now i want to create an array  with dimensions [1,npoints].
I can't think how to do this.
For example table=[1,npoints]

Also, i want to evaluate this:

```
for i in range(1,npoints):
    if experiment[i,0]**2+experiment[i,1]**2 >1:
        table[i]=0
    else:
        table[i]=1
```

I am trying to evaluate the `experiment[:,0]**2+experiment[:,1]**2` and if it is >1 then an element in table becomes 0 else becomes 1.

The table must give me sth like [1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0].
I can't try it because i can't create the array "table".
Also,if there is a better way (with list comprehensions) to produce this..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
table = (experiment[:,0]**2 + experiment[:,1]**2 <= 1).astype(int)
```

You can leave off the `astype(int)` call if you're happy with an array of booleans rather than an array of integers.  As Joe Kington points out, this can be simplified to:

```
table = 1 - (experiment**2).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
```

If you really need to create the `table` array up front, you could do:

```
table = zeros(npoints, dtype=int)
```

(assuming that you've already import `zeros` from numpy).  Then your for loop should work as written.

Aside:  I suspect that you want `range(npoints)` rather than `range(1, npoints)` in your `for` statement.

Edit:  just noticed that I had the 1s and 0s backwards.  Now fixed.

Comment: It's a bit cleaner to just do `table = numpy.sum(experiment**2, axis=1).astype(int)`  or equivalently `table = (experiment**2).sum(axis=1).astype(int)`

Comment: @Joe Kington: Hmm.  That gives the reverse of what's wanted;  I added an extra `1 - ` to fix it.

Comment: Well, I misread things... I didn't notice the `<=1`, I was just referring to squaring and adding the two columns seperately.   My equivalent would be `(experiment**2).sum(axis=1) <= 1` (with wrapping the whole thing in `astype(int)`, if ints are what the OP wants.  That'll teach me to comment without reading everythign!

Comment: @Mark Dickinson:Thanks!It works fine!I wanted to ask how the <=1 evaluates the expression.I mean ,ok it means what i want(it implements the if statement) but where can i use such "tricks"?From where can i learn?Thanks again!